# Converting points on Plane in Perspective-space to 2D Coordinate points

Tags: geometry

Augmented Reality scenario: I have a piece of paper on the table and a camera pointed at it, the piece of paper appear to be *slanted* with two pair of edges going towards two vanishing points.

Say I draw a dot on that paper, how would I calculate its coordinate on the paper-plane, just by knowing the on-screen coords of the four vertices of the paper, as well as the on-screen coords of the dot?

Any point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated :D I don't even know what this process is called.

Thanks! ~Xrave

Comment: You may be interested in this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96662/augmented-reality-transformation-matrix-optimization

Answer (score 1):

What you seek to accomplish is to invert the [perspective transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) that produced your image.
Although I am sure this is not the ideal reference (probably textbooks on image processing and computer vision are more direct), here is one: "Inverse Perspective Transformation for Video Surveillance" by Theo E. Schoutena, and Egon L. van den Broekb, PDF [here](http://www.mbsd.cs.ru.nl/publications/papers/ths/Scho08b/inversepersp.pdf).

Comment: Oh, thanks! This means I can use a rectangle to first obtain the "orientation" of the camera - i believe i saw that somewhere before, and then use the algorithm in there to get the dot-position translated...