# Augmented Reality Transformation Matrix Optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, projective-geometry

i am a software developer, i'm working on an Augmented Reality system.
I'd like to receive some advice in order to optimize my math model. My program has to be slim and fast.
**Here's the situation**:

This is a photo of my marker:
[image]

I want to find the transformation matrix that "normalize" the photo in order to get this:
[image]

I have 4 angles coordinates of the marker:
$$P{1} = (352; 90)$$
$$P{2} = (93; 384)$$
$$P{3} = (852; 283)$$
$$P{4} = (663; 677)$$

Equation to find a generic projective transformation of a point P(x,y):

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
 x' \\
 y' \\
 z' \\
 \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
 h_{1,1} & h_{1,2} & h_{1,3} \\
 h_{2,1} & h_{2,2} & h_{2,3} \\
 h_{3,1} & h_{3,2} & h_{3,3}
 \end{array}\right]*
\left[\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
 1 \\
 \end{array}\right]$$

[image: Awesome draw of the model]

In algebric form (we don't need z' and it is divided in x' and y'):
$$x' = \frac{h_{11}x + h_{12}y + h_{13}}{h_{31}x + h_{32}y + h_{33}}$$
$$y' = \frac{h_{21}x + h_{22}y + h_{23}}{h_{31}x + h_{32}y + h_{33}}$$

Supposing that H(3,3) is 1, I can find H by solving this 8 equation by 8 variables system:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x_{1}*x'_{1} & -y_{1}*x'_{1} \\
 x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x_{2}*x'_{2} & -y_{2}*x'_{2} \\
 x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x_{3}*x'_{3} & -y_{3}*x'_{3} \\
 x_{4} & y_{4} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x_{4}*x'_{4} & -y_{4}*x'_{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 & -x_{1}*y'_{1} & -y_{1}*y'_{1} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 & -x_{2}*y'_{2} & -y_{2}*y'_{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 & -x_{3}*y'_{3} & -y_{3}*y'_{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{4} & y_{4} & 1 & -x_{4}*y'_{4} & -y_{4}*y'_{4}
 \end{array}\right]*
\left[\begin{array}{c}
 h_{1,1} \\
 h_{1,2} \\
 h_{1,3} \\
 h_{2,1} \\
 h_{2,2} \\
 h_{2,3} \\
 h_{3,1} \\
 h_{3,2}
 \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
 x'_{1} \\
 x'_{2} \\
 x'_{3} \\
 x'_{4} \\
 y'_{1} \\
 y'_{2} \\
 y'_{3} \\
 y'_{4}
 \end{array}\right]$$

Considering that the final marker will have mx as width and my as height, the transformations of my 4 initial points will be:
$$P'{1} = (0; 0)$$
$$P'{2} = (0; my)$$
$$P'{3} = (mx; 0)$$
$$P'{4} = (mx; my)$$

So the system, in my case, become:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x_{3}*mx & -y_{3}*mx \\
 x_{4} & y_{4} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x_{4}*mx & -y_{4}*mx \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 & -x_{2}*my & -y_{2}*my \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{4} & y_{4} & 1 & -x_{4}*my & -y_{4}*my
 \end{array}\right]*
\left[\begin{array}{c}
 h_{1,1} \\
 h_{1,2} \\
 h_{1,3} \\
 h_{2,1} \\
 h_{2,2} \\
 h_{2,3} \\
 h_{3,1} \\
 h_{3,2}
 \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 mx \\
 mx \\
 0 \\
 my \\
 0 \\
 my
 \end{array}\right]$$

This model works: i tried in Matlab and Java.
My question is: **could it be simplified or optimized?**
This system has a lot of zeros, and that means that it has little "information"...
Should I change something?
(I could consider mx and my equals to 1, in order to semplify the system even more. but i'd like to reduce the number of equations if it's possible)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the transformation you are looking for is of some specific form which has dependence between elements, I think it is not possible to reduce the number of the equations. You have 9 unknowns here, so 9 equations is the minimum for a single solution. Since you are looking for projection, I may guess that the transformation of it is not of general form, so it might be a good idea to think about how the matrix should look.

For implementation, instead of using a linear equations solver during run-time, , I suggest to try solve the equation off line and then construct equations for each unknown.

Comment: sincerly, i don't have any idea about how the matrix should look :( where could i find some documentation?

Comment: I can guess (again, only a guess) that it is the inverse of a multiplication of a perspective and a rotation. You can test this empirically by photo-shooting the marker at a known angle, calculating the inverse matrix (perspective should be know from camera parameters) and comparing with the solution of the linear system that you already developed.